# Apply function to data frames grouped by

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, apply

I want to apply a function to subsets of a data frame which originate from the initial one after having grouped by some variables. I am therefore looking for an equivalent wrapper as `apply` or similars, taking as input an entire data frame and outputting a vector. This is because the function at hand needs entries from row and columns in different places all together and cannot be simplified down to only use rows and columns and hence be of the form of `lapply` or `apply(df, 1(2),...)`

Let us consider the below example:

```
iris   <- data.table(iris)

my.function <- function(sub.data){
v <- c(NA)
    for(j in 2:dim(sub.data)[1]){
        if(sub.data[j,1, with = FALSE] > sub.data[j-1,2, with = FALSE]+2){
            v[j] <- "ok"
        } else {
            v[j] <- "not ok"    
        }
    }
    return(v)
}
```

the execution `my.function(iris)` works properly, but assume I want to apply the function only on groups having the same Species. As such, in the `data.table` syntax, this should look like:

```
results <- iris[,
                wrapper(.SD, my.function),
                by = Species
                ]
```

where `wrapper` is the environment I am looking for, of the type `lapply` or similar. Equivalently, one might use the package `dplyr` too, but I do not know what the corresponding grammar could be: I have tried

```
results <- iris %>%
                group_by(Species) %>%
                     summarise(results = my.function(iris))
```

but that does not seem to produce the correct result, as it runs nevertheless against the entire data set for each species, instead of separating into subsets.

Comment: Do you want something like `ddply()` from the package `plyr`?

Comment: `summarise(results = my.function(.))` ?

Comment: @rawr People don't usually check the comments while answering.  Please consider to post that as an answer.

Comment: @rawr Yes, that does the job. Likewise for `ddply`, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you don't need `wrapper` here. Simply running your function on .SD does what you need.

```
library(data.table)
#your function works with a data.table
#by below will create smaller data tables on which you can directly
#run my.function on
iris[, my.function(.SD), by=Species]
```

Output:

```
       Species     V1
  1:    setosa     NA
  2:    setosa not ok
  3:    setosa not ok
  4:    setosa not ok
  5:    setosa not ok
 ---                 
146: virginica     ok
147: virginica     ok
148: virginica     ok
149: virginica     ok
150: virginica     ok
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the objective here to not use packages?

Is the output vector to have the same length as the number of rows of the data.frame?  If so try `ave` where we have used a test `my.function` which returns the number of rows times the number of columns of its input data frame:

```
my.function <- function(x) prod(dim(x)) # test function
ave(1:nrow(iris), iris$Species, FUN = function(ix) my.function(iris[ix, ]))
##  [1] 250 250 250 250 250 250 250 250 ...
```

The above also works if my.function returns a vector the same length as the number of rows of input.

If you just want a length 3 vector in this case:

```
tapply(1:nrow(iris), iris$Species, function(ix) my.function(iris[ix, ]))
## setosa versicolor  virginica 
##    250        250        250
```

or `by` :

```
c(by(iris, iris$Species, my.function))
## setosa versicolor  virginica 
##    250        250        250
```

or `sapply/split`:

```
sapply(split(iris, iris$Species), my.function)
## setosa versicolor  virginica 
##    250        250        250
```